# Creating a SQL Server Trace programmatically?

Tags: sql-server, database

Anyone have any snippets for creating a SQL Server trace on the fly? I've found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188662.aspx) on MSDN but it only seems to output to the file system. What about logging it to a DB table or returning it via some sort of UDF? Ideally it would be used to create a debugging tool, so it would be nice to wrap it up in something that could be turned on and off easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Server side SQL Trace not using the rowset provider can **only** trace to the file system.

Profiler offers the option of saving to a table but does this by consuming the rowset output and sending it back to the server which is quite inefficient.

You can easily access these server side traces though as follows and load them into a table yourself (snippet below returns the output of the default trace)

```
select t.* from
fn_trace_getinfo(default) i 
cross apply 
 sys.fn_trace_gettable(cast(i.value as nvarchar(4000)),DEFAULT) t
 where i.traceid=1 and i.property=2
```

Comment: Is it possible to perform a trace using the rowset provider?

Comment: @jacko - Not straightforwardly. You can use profiler to trace profiler to see what it is doing but I don't think the output is documented anywhere. There might be something in the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace` namespace to do this from a .NET application though.

Comment: I've decided to select this as the answer even though I've followed Martins advice down the route of a app using the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace namespace...